# ¿Por qué no puedo llamar a un objeto tipo String en un metodo static?

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño código en el cual creo un objeto `String` llamado `name` y le doy un valor por defecto en el constructor y llamo ese mismo objeto con un `System.out.println`. El error que me sale es cuando el método por donde llamo el objeto es `static` y me sale error. Cuando lo quito, me corre bien. ¿Por qué?

Según yo, no es necesario usar un objeto para llamar a un método `static`, por ejemplo el método `main` de los programas en java.

¿Por qué al llamar a un objeto en un metodo `static` me sale error?

Este es el código:

```
package Methods;

/**
 *
 * @author sommer0123
 */
public class TheMethodJava {
    String  name =  new  String();

    public TheMethodJava(){
        this.name = "Gilberto Quintero Armenta";
    }

    public static void GetName(String myname){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puede que hayas querido poner myname en vez de name en el System.out.println?

Comment: Ya le hice edición a la pregunta, pero, por favor, para beneficio de nuestros ojitos, usa puntos al final de la frases.

Comment: Además, aunque es obvio para los que van a leer tu pregunta, si la pregunta se trata de un error que recibes, nunca te limites a decir simplemente que recibes un error. Sé específico y detalla el error exacto que recibes. Y un punto más: en la pregunta argumentas que *no es necesario usar un objeto para llamar a un método static, por ejemplo el método main de los programas en java.*. Para validar tu argumento, incluye un código que demuestre este punto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a la especificación de Java, cuando marcas un método con el modificador `static` estás indicando que ese método se invocara sin hacer referencia a ningún objeto en particular. Cuando invocas a un método, habitualmente lo llamas por medio de un objeto en particular, considera la siguiente definición de la clase A:

```
public class A {

    String nombre = "Daniel";
    int edad = 24;

    public static void saludar() {
        System.out.println("¡Hola!");
    }

    public void despedirse() {
        System.out.println("¡Adiós! " + nombre);
    }

    public boolean mayorDeEdad() {
        return edad >= 18;
    }

}
```

Esta clase A tiene dos métodos: uno llamados `saludar` que al ejecutarse imprime en pantalla "¡Hola!" y otro que al invocarse imprime en pantalla "¡Adiós! Daniel". Para poder invocar al método `despedirse` tienes que crear una variable que sea instancia de la clase A y usar el operador punto (.) para llamar a ese método.

```
A a = new A();
a.despedirse();
```

El anterior código imprime en pantalla "¡Adiós! Daniel". Cuando creas un objeto de la clase A este objeto crea una copia de todas sus variables de instancia, en este caso, tiene una copia propia de la variable de tipo `String` nombre cuyo valor es "Daniel". Cuando llamas al método `despedirse` esta usa el valor de la variable `nombre` del objeto donde se invoca (en este caso, la variable a) y sabe cómo ejecutarse.

Ahora, considera el método `saludar`. Al estar marcado con el modificador  `static`, este método se ejecuta sin necesidad de crear una instancia de un objeto en particular, por lo tanto se invoca así:

```
A.saludar();
```

e imprimirá en pantalla "¡Hola!". Otra forma de pensar en estos métodos es que la 'propiedad' de los mismos les pertenece a la clase (en este caso la clase A) y no a las instancias de la clase (como la variable a, aunque también puede invocarse como a.saludar() pero no es habitual).

**El problema**

Como mencioné antes, cada objeto/referencia de una clase en Java tiene una copia de sus propias variables de instancia, por ejemplo:

```
A a = new A();
A b = new A();
```

la variable a y b tienen sus propias copias de la variable entera `edad`. Por lo tanto, cualquier método que ejecutes hará operaciones sobre sus propias variables. Pero ahora, si ejecutas un método estático `static`, al ser un método que le pertenece a la clase y no a la variable ¿qué sentido tiene que acceda a una variable de instancia de una clase si para que el método se ejecute no necesita la instancia de la clase?.

Esto quiere decir que en tu ejemplo, el método estático `GetName` de tu clase `TheMethodJava` puede invocarse así:

```
TheMethodJava.GetName();
```

pero, si no existe un objeto creado de tipo `TheMethodJava` ¿a cuál variable llamada name haría referencia?

Por este motivo, el [estándar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1) de Java menciona que ocurrirá un error de compilación si en una clase estática (aquella que tiene al menos un método estático) intentas usar una variable de una clase que no es estática.

**La solución**

Una posible solución es que elimines el modificador `static` del método, o que añadas el modificador `static` a tu variable `name`. De esta forma, el método podrá hacer uso de la variable, ya que ni el método ni la variable necesitan una referencia para ser invocados.

Comment: Exelente explicacion :)

Answer (score 0):

Un método estático no puede acceder a ningún componente (método o variable) no estático porque los componentes no estáticos se manejan a nivel de instancia es decir necesitamos la instancia de una clases(Objetos) para que estos componentes "existan", mientras que los componentes estáticos no necesitan una instancia, pensemos de la siguiente manera: estático (static) = clase, no-estático = instancia.

Mientras que un método no estático puede acceder a componentes estáticos y no estáticos.